# fireplace hearth

Tags: fireplace, hearth

[image]

I was helping to redo the hearth on a 100 y/o fireplace, and as I pulled up the bricks and moved sand out of the way I noticed wood installed on an angle (subfloor?). The fireplace is in the middle of the room on a 100 y/o house built on stilts/pilings.

I've spoken with a few people but they don't know enough about fireplaces built this long ago.

Is the wood/subfloor suppose to be like this? It's a pretty big gap.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: is the wood suppose to be like this or something under the house collapse?

Comment: Oh that's interesting, does it have same pitch on the other side?

Comment: no it doesnt have the pitch on other side

Comment: I'd think if you kept digging at the front you'd find a spot where it either cracked or just ends, but hopefully someone else is familiar with this type of setup, I'm out of my depth, just fascinated.

Comment: lol ok,seeing its 100 y/o fireplace i might be out of luck since all the old school masons would be passed by now.a pitch like that on anything ive ever done was used for some type of run off

Answer (score 2):

The wood was used as a concrete form for that back in the day. Concrete was poured to the sub level needed top hold the finish hearth. It typically extended into the fire box, actually it was poured usually before the firebox is built and was used as a base the continue the firebox construction. It was poured after the brick is built up to the level where the concrete could be poured 4+" thick. The reason for the tapered form are such as the concrete doesn't need to be that thick at the edge. 2-3" at the thin edge works since it get another covering over it.

Comment: Does the lack of taper on the other side strike you as odd?

Comment: Not at all, usually the taper is only on one side it does not return around the two short sides, it is only on the one long side.

Comment: I want to add the taper is to help keep the slab balanced so to speak, since it is cantilevered.